# Visual studio debugger skips asserts/breakpoints

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

Visual studio debugger has always been broken ah handling `__debugbreak` statements. Depending on how code is written/structured, it could silently skip the statements hiding bugs/asserts that would remain unnoticed. Any idea what's wrong? I was trying to report the issue to Microsoft VS team and they keep rejecting it as if they cannot repro the bug.

Here's simple code that clearly exposes broken VS debugger in current VS 2022 version 17.8.5 (as of January 2024).

```
#include <windows.h>
int main()
{
    do { Sleep(1); __debugbreak(); } while (false);
    do { Sleep(1); __debugbreak(); } while (false);
    do { Sleep(1); __debugbreak(); } while (false);
}
```

In VS debug build simply pressing F10 (step through) under the debugger all the `__debugbreak` statements do not trigger debugger breaks, while these clearly MUST all trigger. Pressing F5 (run under the debugger) does trigger breaks, but F10/F11 does not.

Any ideas why it's broken, and why MSFT thinks that it's ok? By the  way, in older VS versions it was much worse that it is in the latest VS.

In case if anybody wondering what's the deal with these `Sleep(1)` calls: removing them fixes the bug. Over the years, I've noticed some weird combinations where asserts/debugbreaks didn't work. This is just an example.

Comment: Why is this relevant? If you press F10, you _are_ already debugging and stopping on the next line.

Comment: Stopping on the line does not mean that debug break was triggered. If you remove `Sleep(1);` calls, then stepping with F10/F11 does trigger breaks.